# Cannot use scp with wdmycloud

Tags: ssh, scp

I can successfully log in to my cloud as root or another user I added. I need to use the `scp` command to send an image to my folder.  It keeps asking for the password and saying its wrong when I know it's right. `Ben@192.168.1.20` is my local computer but I have to identify the source or it will say "no such file or directory". Also, Ben can be capital or lowercase it does not make a difference.

```
WDMyCloud:~# scp -v Ben@192.168.1.20:/Users/***/Desktop/Apple.jpg root@192.168.1.4:/DataVolume/shares/Ben
Executing: /usr/bin/ssh '-x' '-oClearAllForwardings=yes' '-n' '-v' '-l' 'Ben' '--' '192.168.1.20' 'scp -v' '/Users/Ben/Desktop/Apple.jpg' 'root@192.168.1.4:/DataVolume/shares/Ben'
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.20 [192.168.1.20] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 33:44:49:5a:89:04:4e:92:7c:6a:ed:f7:d8:1d:24:5a
debug1: Host '192.168.1.20' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:

(Now I enter it and it refuses)

Password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
Password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
Password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
WDMyCloud:~#
```

Comment: Could you un-hide the IP addresses here?  192.168.1.* addresses aren't security sensitive in a home network, you've only hidden half of them anyway, and it makes it way more confusing to follow what's going on.

Comment: Thanks.  So if I'm reading this right, you're logged into your WDMyCloud (.1.4), and you want the WDMyCloud to pull a file from your local computer (.1.20) onto its own hard drive?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: I seem to always get the error Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't secure copy to wdmycloud with ssh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216869/cant-secure-copy-to-wdmycloud-with-ssh)

Comment: I answered on this one and the other one doesn't have an answer yet, so voting to close the other one.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and then on again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that `scp` does interesting things when you give it two IP addresses to work with.  If your source or destination is the machine running the `scp` command, then one of your paths should be local.  If you're on the MyCloud, try this:

```
WDMyCloud:~# scp Ben@192.168.1.20:/Users/***/Desktop/Apple.jpg /DataVolume/shares/Ben
```

Or if you're on your local machine:

```
LocalComputer:~# scp /Users/***/Desktop/Apple.jpg root@192.168.1.4:/DataVolume/shares/Ben
```

If you're curious about what's happening in this case, though, you can look at the "`Executing:`" output from your `scp -v`.

```
Executing: /usr/bin/ssh '-x' '-oClearAllForwardings=yes' '-n' '-v' '-l' 'Ben' '--' '192.168.1.20' 'scp -v' '/Users/Ben/Desktop/Apple.jpg' 'root@192.168.1.4:/DataVolume/shares/Ben'
```

One interesting thing about `ssh` is that you can use it to run a single command immediately instead of an interactive shell.  What is happening here is that instead of copying the file itself, your `scp` is asking 192.168.1.20 to handle the copying.  It's as if you ran the following:

```
WDMyCloud:~# ssh Ben@192.168.1.20
Password: [password to Ben@LocalComputer goes here]
LocalComputer:~$ scp /Users/***/Desktop/Apple.jpg root@192.168.1.4:/DataVolume/shares/Ben
Password: [password to root@WDMyCloud goes here]
LocalComputer:~$ exit
```

Why does `scp` do this?  It's an efficiency measure that makes a lot more sense for the following case:

```
LocalComputer:~$ scp Ben@192.168.1.99:/path/to/Apple.jpg root@192.168.1.4:/DataVolume/shares/Ben
```

In this case, the file is on one remote computer and you want to copy it onto another remote computer.  If your local computer did the copying, it would be tied up all throughout the copy process, ferrying bits from one remote computer to the other.  It's a lot more efficient to have one of the remotes connect directly to the other.

Comment: WDMyCloud:~# scp Ben@192.168.1.20:/Users/***/Desktop/Apple.jpg /DataVolume/shares/Ben
Worked!!!!! I totally get it. I was on WDMyCloud so when I entered the destination directory, I didnt need ben@192.168.1.4 because that is itself (local). Instead of trying to ask my laptop to put a file on the drive when I was logged into the drive via ssh, I needed to ask the drive to pull the file from my laptop. Thanks so much for the help Jander!!